# How to find out External SD card mount block?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, external-sd, formatting, sony-xperia-z3-compact

Im going to reformat my sdcard to have an ext4 partition for installing linux on my phone.
I'm using Aparted app to do this:
[image]
5GB Fat32 for android to work with.
10GB ext4 for Linux.
1GB swap for increasing memory.

It has an internal storage protection so it won't wipe the internal memory.
By default it wont format because it says it's currently on internal storage.
[image]

So i searched a bit and found that external storage is "mmcblk1p1" mostly.
I checked out the settings and it was set to this:
[image]

So i added a "p1" at the end of it but I see this result...i think there is no such a thing?
[image]

I also tried the "detected devices" option and taped on "usbdisk" but still no good results:
[image]
[image]

I tried the "mount" option but I'm not that professional to findout something from these:

su (i set this starter "su" on terminal so it's always on root)
u0_a247@D5803:/ $ su
root@D5803:/ # mount 
rootfs / rootfs ro,seclabel,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,size=892968k,nr_inodes=163604,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,seclabel,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
selinuxfs /sys/fs/selinux selinuxfs rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=892968k,nr_inodes=163604,mode=750,gid=1000 0 0
none /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,relatime,memory 0 0
tmpfs /mnt tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=892968k,nr_inodes=163604,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/memcg cgroup rw,relatime,memory 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,relatime,size=892968k,nr_inodes=163604,mode=755 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,discard,noauto_da_alloc,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache /cache ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,relatime,discard,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/apps_log /idd ext4 rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,discard,nobarrier,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/LTALabel /lta-label ext4 ro,context=u:object_r:lta_label:s0,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /storage tmpfs rw,seclabel,relatime,size=892968k,nr_inodes=163604,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
/dev/block/loop0 /system/etc/product/orig.applications squashfs ro,seclabel,relatime 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/default/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/read/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/write/emulated fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0
/dev/block/vold/public:179,65 /mnt/media_rw/039B-1DF0 vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/vold/public:179,65 /mnt/secure/asec vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007,dmask=0007,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/default/039B-1DF0 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/039B-1DF0 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/read/039B-1DF0 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0
/dev/fuse /mnt/runtime/write/039B-1DF0 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other,allow_utime_grp 0 0
root@D5803:/ #

Wich block is my external sdcard???
I gotta tell my internal is 16GB and my external is 16GB too...Yeah I think that may make some confusions...
I will try to borrow a 8GB from a friend and see if the Aparted changed to 8GB or not...if yes...i think it just misunderstands the storages, I will try it ASAP and tell the result.

> > I'm posting this from phone so there is no highlight or code option to make things prettier and organized, so I'm happy if you do it.
> >     Thanks in Advance.

INFO:
D5803 
Xperia Z3 Compact
Stock kernel
SliMM Rom
Android 6.0.1
Locked bootloader

I found out my SD card won't show up on this app too:
[image]

But ES file manager finds it and I have access to it fully...anything works:
[image]

Maybe it's because that I mounted it as "portable storage"?
[image]